# prove this identity in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, prove for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu (A) < \infty$ and $\int_{A^c} \, |f| \, d\mu < \epsilon$.

I don't have a clue where to start with except that $\int_{A^c} \, |f| \, d\mu = \sup_{s \le \, \mathcal{X}_{A^c}  |f|} \int_{\Omega} s \, d\mu$ where $s$ is simple function, which doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Consider the set where $\lvert f\rvert$ is "large enough".

Comment: The key is that $f \in \mathcal L^1$ so that $\int |f| d\mu$ is a real number. Use this in tandem with Daniel's hint.

Comment: I want to find a set $A$ such that either $|f|$ is small in $A^c$ or the set $A^c$ is small. Would $\mu(A^c) < \epsilon$ imply the integral is less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: @ywx Check out my answer and see if it makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you started the problem isn't bad.  That definition will be very helpful.  Here, I will help you start the problem:

First, given $\epsilon > 0$ can we find a simple function $s$ with $0 \leq s \leq |f|$ and $\int \limits_{\Omega} |f| \,d\mu < \int \limits_{\Omega} s \,d\mu + \epsilon$?  The answer is yes.  But why?

Now, consider $A = \{ x \mid s(x) > 0 \}$.  Does $A$ have finite measure?  Again, the answer is yes.  But why?

Now, consider that $\int \limits_{A^{c}} |f| \,d\mu \leq \int \limits_{\Omega} |f| \,d\mu$ (why?).  Also, what is the value of $s(x)$ on $A^{c}$?  What does this mean for the value of $\int \limits_{A^{c}} s \,d\mu$?

Finally, finish the problem by observing that $\int \limits_{A^{c}} |f| \,d\mu = \int \limits_{A^{c}} |f| - s + s \,d\mu$.  What can we do with this? (Hint: the integral is linear.)  You'll also need to apply a slightly modified version of the inequality we initially found.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the only thing that requires a bit of work is to show the set $A$ has finite measure. Maybe there is a simpler way but I can first show $\int_A s\, d\mu \le \infty$. Then, say $s$ has canonical representation $s = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \mathcal{X}_{B_k}$, and use the fact that $\{B_k\}$ are pairwise disjoint and $A=\cup_{k=1}^n B_k$ to deduce that $\mu (A) < \infty$

Comment: @ywx That's exactly right.  Your explanation for why $A$ has finite measure is great.  I just want to add that when you represent $s$ canonically, if $a_{k} = \infty$ for some $k$, then it must be that $\mu(B_{k}) = 0$ since $s$ has finite integral.  But it looks like you already understood that.

Comment: Oops, I meant $\int_A s \, d\mu < \infty$